# Apagar o último dígito inserido

Tags: javascript, html

Estou criando uma calculadora, usando HTML e JavaScript.  Meu objetivo era que ela tive-se um botão que permite-se o usuário apagar o último valor digitado (por exemplo, o usuário digita o número `9` e depois `8` e forma `98`, mas ele quer apagar o `8`, logo ele aperta esse botão para o valor voltar a ser só `9`), mas não estou conseguindo criar uma função para isso.

Gostaria de um código, em JavaScript, para resolver esse problema.

[image: Imagem da minha calculadora.]

Answer (score 1):

Usa o metodo `substring`, `input.value = inputText.substring(0,inputText.length-1);`

```html
<input id="input" type="text"/>
<button onclick="apagar()">Apagar</button>

<script>
function apagar() {
  let input = document.getElementById('input');
  let inputText = input.value;
  input.value = inputText.substring(0,inputText.length-1);
  console.log(input.value);
}</script>
```

Comment: Ou (se a entrada for um número válido) `Math.floor(inputText/10)`.

Comment: É... se tiver com máscara, formatação etc... Mas ele não disse nada.

Comment: Cara, funciono do jeito que eu queria, muito obrigado =)

Comment: Marque a resposta como solução então. O usuário que te ajudou merece colher os louros

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `slice`:

```
var str=document.getElementById("campo-com-o-valor").value;
str = str.slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: Desculpe o formato, respondo pelo celular